# android_cmake finds boost include wrong

Tags: android, boost, cmake

i discovered strange behavior of android_cmake and boost. i start cmake using

```
cmake ../ -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/android/android-cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=/opt/android/android-cmake/common-libs/boost -DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR=/opt/android/android-cmake/common-libs/boost/boost-trunk/boost -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=/opt/android/android-cmake/common-libs/boost/libs/armeabi-v7a -DBoost_DEBUG=1
```

as you can see all 3 boost variables BOOST_ROOT, BOOST_INCLUDEDIR and BOOST_LIBRARYDIR are set. the boost is found by "find_host_package" function. below is a part of an output:

```
-- [ /opt/sw/cmake-2.8.10.2/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:646 ]   BOOST_ROOT = /opt/android/android-cmake/common-libs/boost
-- [ /opt/sw/cmake-2.8.10.2/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:648 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = /opt/android/android-cmake/common-libs/boost/boost-trunk/boost
-- [ /opt/sw/cmake-2.8.10.2/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:650 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = /opt/android/android-cmake/common-libs/boost/libs/armeabi-v7a
-- [ /opt/sw/cmake-2.8.10.2/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:705 ] Include debugging info:
-- [ /opt/sw/cmake-2.8.10.2/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:707 ]   _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = /opt/android/android-cmake/common-libs/boost/boost-trunk/boost;/opt/android/android-cmake/common-libs/boost/include;/opt/android/android-cmake/common-libs/boost;C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/boost/include;/boost;/sw/local/include
-- [ /opt/sw/cmake-2.8.10.2/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:734 ] location of version.hpp: /usr/local/include/boost/version.hpp
```

as you can see, boost take version.hpp not from set location, but from

```
/usr/local/include/boost/version.hpp
```

even though my specified location *does* contain version.hpp:

```
/opt/android/android-cmake/common-libs/boost/boost-trunk/boost/version.hpp
```

now i cant be sure what is going on and where cmake takes the boost.. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to forcefully exclude the default search,

> Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS  - Set to ON to disable searching in locations
>   not specified by these hint variables. Default is OFF.

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/module/FindBoost.html

Try,

```
cmake ../ -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/android/android-cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=/opt/android/android-cmake/common-libs/boost -DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR=/opt/android/android-cmake/common-libs/boost/boost-trunk/boost -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=/opt/android/android-cmake/common-libs/boost/libs/armeabi-v7a -DBoost_DEBUG=1 -DBoost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS=ON
```

Comment: it forced cmake for following message: Could NOT find Boost, unable to find boost header files, please set BOOST_ROOT and includes etc. Even though they are specifically set and are present in debug output... Ridiculous.

Comment: It could be that it finds a version that it doesn't expect. The versions that it expects would probably be in the android.toolchain.cmake fiel. Try changing the cmake file and setting  `Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS` to include the version you have on your system.

Comment: i added -DBoost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS=1.55 (together with NO_SYSTEM_PATHS=ON), still same effect: could not find boost. anyway, the version 1.55 is found even without mentioned key and listed within  _boost_TEST_VERSIONS. and if i remove NO_SYSTEM (but add ADDITIONAL) then boost takes /usr/local/include/boost/ directory as default..